# Running a bound service and a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I currently have a bound Service with my Main activity.

I was wondering if it was possible to have a Thread Running inside this bound Service that can pass integers to my Main Activity. This Service needs to auto update my Main Activity's Text View with any new Random number Integer without clicking a button.

Should i look into Handlers?? Or Message/ Bundles??

Any help would be appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: Using Handler you can do it

Comment: Is Handlers the proper way to do it? And if so, how do I pass my current handler from Main Activity to the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define one Receiver your MainActivity and you can use send Broadcast to that receiver to update your UI.. That is a simple way to do it

In your service Just define one intent and put values into it like follwing

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("RECEIVERACTION");
i.putExtra("data", "mydata");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

and in your activity

```
public static class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        textView.setText(data);
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new MainActivity.Receiver(), new IntentFilter("RECEIVERACTION")); dont forget to add the above line in your service

Answer (score 0):

Please go through api guides. Specifically

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

This should give you a pretty good idea to move forward and also code samples

Comment: Hi, I have went through both Documentation and am still a bit confused as to which method is best for this??  All I can see is Messenger?

Comment: yes you can follow the code samples given in the documentation and use messenger.